# Cant display mark title using geojson on googlemaps swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to display data from geojson file to google maps.
i had display lines but i couldn't display data title at google[Here what i got paths only without titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBKFa.png)map

```
 let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dat", ofType: ".geojson")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        geoJsonParser = GMUGeoJSONParser(url: url)
        geoJsonParser.parse()
        renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(map: mapKitC, geometries: geoJsonParser.features)
        for i in geoJsonParser.features {
            if let feature = i as? GMUFeature {
                let properties = feature.properties
                //print(properties?["Name"]! ?? [String:AnyObject]())
                print((properties?["Name"] as! String))
                i.style = GMUStyle(styleID: "feat_1", stroke: UIColor.red, fill: .clear, width: 2, scale: 1, heading: 1, anchor: CGPoint.zero, iconUrl: nil, title: (properties?["Name"] as! String) , hasFill: true, hasStroke: true)
            }
        }
```

here is a simple of json in geojson file

{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "Export_Output_2",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Name": "الجزيرة",
                "description": null,
                "altitudeMode": "clampToGround",
                "REMARKS": "الجزيرة",
                "FID": "1",
                "Field_1": "الجزيرة"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [50.016116765605382, 26.55069039986865],
                            [50.015975528609339, 26.550991875762669],
                            [50.015543249856229, 26.552092609191],
                            [50.014021356227893, 26.555916886985312],
                            [50.013986819836397, 26.555993389005849],
                            [50.0139615327519, 26.55605189831601],
                            [50.013937500451902, 26.556110416304062],
                            [50.013914703626462, 26.556171199925231],
                            [50.013893190939172, 26.556229735340509],
                            [50.013872592497187, 26.55629053416698],
                            [50.013853248846132, 26.556351341673729],
                            [50.013834177740307, 26.5564166652394],
                            [50.010366238955562, 26.55583737812676],
                            [50.010393511923603, 26.555767597848071],
                            [50.010456762048257, 26.555598755587489],
                            [50.010516559775482, 26.555429888414469],
                            [50.010573224326002, 26.555261000355909],
                            [50.010626464910303, 26.555089831406779],
                            [50.010676553278628, 26.554918640545011],
                            [50.011099741935944, 26.553458982554702],
                            [50.011300373154121, 26.552817103722361],
                            [50.011331824976743, 26.55269769626123],
                            [50.011356070762062, 26.552614352208838],
                            [50.011381863106351, 26.55253327596817],
                            [50.011409240723651, 26.552449953630379],
                            [50.011438194289781, 26.552366642218029],
                            [50.01146869440673, 26.552285598614549],
                            [50.011501071619158, 26.55220456712059],
                            [50.01153470354334, 26.552123545223392],
                            [50.011569892050197, 26.552044791201482],
                            [50.011606655769612, 26.551963791005878],
                            [50.011644976066812, 26.551885058683109],
                            [50.011684872292918, 26.55180633727754],
                            [50.01172630602143, 26.55172988360998],
                            [50.012049918940242, 26.551135195177299],
                            [50.012152127902489, 26.550947367255439],
                            [50.013113094152381, 26.549252177776619],
                            [50.016116765605382, 26.55069039986865]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }]}

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic, but it would be helpful if you add some sample data from the geojson file. Good luck!

Comment: @cypark i have edited the question.thanks in advance